# Getting link centered on top of each image

Tags: html, css

I have a php loop that builds a list of images:

```
<?php foreach($imageResult as $im):?>

    <img class="contentImage" src="<?php echo $im['url'] ?>" style="max-width: 150px; height: auto;">
    <a href="deleteImage.php?imageID=<?php echo $im['ID']?>">Delete</a> 

<?php endforeach?>
```

And this builds them 5 to a row (which is how I want to keep them as opposed to 1 per row stacked on top of each other.

The issue is my Delete link shows to the right of each image, running into the next row sometimes.

Is there a better way that I can get my link to display centered on each image?

Comment: Since this is an issue with HTML and CSS, please share the generated HTML code and your corresponding CSS. Otherwise it will be impossible to help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this. You can find an example here https://jsfiddle.net/zot7k0b3/

```css
.box-image {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.box-image:nth-child(6n+6) {
  clear: left;
}

.box-image img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 150px;
}

.box-image a {
  position: absolute;  
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<?php foreach($imageResult as $im):?>
<div class="box-image">
  <img class="contentImage" src="<?php echo $im['url'] ?>">
  <a href="deleteImage.php?imageID=<?php echo $im['ID']?>">Delete</a>
</div>
<?php endforeach?>
```

Comment: I think this will work, thanks! do you know how I can alter it to only make the delete and transparency show on hover?

Answer (score 0):

Your image and link must be contained on some element to you implement this as you want.

My suggestion:

**html:**

```
<ul class="images">
<?php foreach($imageResult as $im):?>
    <li>
        <img class="contentImage" src="<?php echo $im['url'] ?>" style="max-width: 150px; height: auto;">
        <a href="deleteImage.php?imageID=<?php echo $im['ID']?>">Delete</a> 
    </li>
<?php endforeach?>
</ul>
```

**css:**

```
ul.images {
    // The next two lines removes ul appearance.
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
}

ul.images > li {
    position: relative;
}

il.images > li > a {
    position: absolute;

    // Play with this values to position your link in the right place.
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Of course you can use just a div as container, but I like to use `ul` and `li` to keep the html semantic.

Answer (score 0):

Enclose image and link inside a div and add css align center, that will resolve the issue

```css
.contentImageContainer {
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.contentImage {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<?php foreach($imageResult as $im):?>
  <div class="contentImageContainer">
    <img src="<?php echo $im['url'] ?>" style=""/>
    <a href="deleteImage.php?imageID=<?php echo $im['ID']?>">Delete</a>
  </div>
<?php endforeach?>
```